# How to select only these rows where values in all column all the same in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: duplicates, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have time in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
COL1  | COL2
------|--------
12    | 12
15    | 8
10    | 10
...   |....
```

And I need to select only these rows where values in all column all the same, so as a result I need something like below:

```
COL1  | COL2
------|--------
12    | 12
10    | 10
...   |....
```

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide / PROC SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do it.

```
   data have;
        input col1 col2;
        datalines;
    1 2
    2 2
    4 5
    6 7
    7 7
    ;
    run;
```

You can simply use where statement inside proc sql:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select * 
            from have
            where col1=col2
    ;
quit;
```

Or you can use if statement using data step:

```
data want;
    set have;
    if col1 = col2 then output;
run;
```

Comment: Negdo, what if I have more than 2 column for example 4?  if col1 = col2 = col3 = col4 then output; ?

Comment: Yes, if there are more than 2 columns you can equate all of them. But if there are too many of them I would aproach the issue a bit differently.

Comment: Negdo, your answer is of course great and I gave you best answer, but I ask this question in bad wat, I modify that, could you look at my second question, please ? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723352/how-to-select-duplicates-rows-with-duplicates-in-each-column-in-sas-enterprise-g