# How to select duplicates rows with duplicates in each column in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have time in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 | 44 |
| 15 | 8 | 2 |
| 10 | 12 | 44 |

And I need to select duplicated rows --> select duplicate rows, but only those where duplicates occur in each column

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 | 44 |
| 10 | 12 | 44 |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide / PROC SQL ?

Comment: No, it does not, because in my previou question I asked it wrong, I need to select rows which occures duplicates ich all column, do yo understand it based on example above ? :)

Comment: Are you looking for a point and click method in the Enterprise Guide front end? Or do you instead want some SAS code you can run using whatever method you are connecting to SAS whether with Enterprise Guide or some other way?

Comment: Tom, I need some  SAS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the observations that occur only once then you could do something like:

```
 proc sort data=have out=want ;
    by col1 col2 col3 ;
 run;
 data want;
   set want;
   by col1 col2 col3 ;
   if not (first.col3 and last.col3) ;
 run;
```

The unique rows are the only rows in their by grouping, so they are both the first row and the last row.

Here is a trick to use if there are a lot of variables and you are not sure which one will end up last if you use the _all_ variable list.  Just add any one to the end and use that.

```
 proc sort data=have out=want ;
    by _all_;
 run;
 data want;
   set want;
   by _all_ col2;
   if not (first.col2 and last.col2) ;
 run;
```

Comment: Tom, what does in mean: if not (first.col3 and last.col3) ; what is this line of code for?

Comment: It is for selecting only rows that are not unique.

Comment: When you use BY in a data step SAS will create FIRST. and LAST. binary flags to indicate if the observation is the first or the last in the by group.  The unique observations will be both the first and the last.  The flags are nested by the order the variables are listed in the BY statement.  So you only need to test the last variable in the BY statement for this uniqueness test.

Comment: Tom, seems logic, thank you very much, I gave best asnwer! :)